# Automatic TRUNCATE table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, truncate

I am looking for a way to automatically clean table in MySQL once per day. Is this possible without using cron? The best solution would be a trigger, but any solution is applicable.

Comment: Triggers should be avoided when possible. They typically create more issues when it comes to maintenance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One option is MySQL's [`EVENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html) scheduler:

```
CREATE EVENT e_daily
    ON SCHEDULE
        EVERY 1 DAY
        STARTS '2014-02-23 05:00:00' -- Time to start
    COMMENT 'Descriptive comment'
    DO
        TRUNCATE yourtable;
```

[How to enable event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-configuration.html)

Comment: Don't forget to 'set global event_scheduler=on', which is off by default.