# How to automatic truncate table in MySQL every 3 months?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, truncate

I have a PHP/MySQL project having 15 tables. One of  table name `tbl_user_log`, where all user log will saved. I want to empty or truncate this table in every 3 month.How could I do this using trigger or any solution is applicable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatic TRUNCATE table in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21956291/automatic-truncate-table-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a cronjob to a certain route of your project to perform following sql:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_user_log
```

See this website: http://setcronjob.com

Or you can simply use mysql EVENTs.

Answer (score 0):

It may helps you

```
declare @tbl nvarchar(max)='table_name'
if (
       (select create_date FROM
        sys.tables where name=@tbl)
        <=  (SELECT DATEADD(month,-3, GETDATE()))
begin
truncate table @tbl
end
else
select 'table creation date is not more than 3 months'
```

better you can put this in a procedure and u can directly pass table name as input and can wrk efficently