# how to delete some record using event that created 3 days ago in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

anyone have idea to make event that can auto delete some record 3 days ago in mysql?

Comment: you can have a cronjob :)

Comment: use SQL Server Agent or refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18275386/how-to-automatically-delete-records-in-sql-server-after-a-certain-amount-of-time

Comment: You can check [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36175959/how-to-automatically-delete-every-x-minutes). Using `MySQL Event Scheduler` you can accomplish this.

Comment: Write a php script, which will run daily via cron process to delete events which are 3 days old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a field that stores the date of the update records, you can use MySql Event Sheduler.

Run in console:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler=ON;
```

And to create an event, such as:

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
       ON SCHEDULE EVERY 3 DAY
       DO DELETE FROM mytable WHERE mytable.update_date <= (DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL 3 DAY));
```

See more: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html